# Python - calling multiprocessing.pool inside a daemon

Tags: python, multiprocessing, daemon

I have a `Python` script which spawns a daemon process. Inside the process, I am using `multiprocessing.pool` to run `1` to `4` processes simultaneously.

When I run this outside the daemon process, it works perfectly (i.e., when I set `run_from_debugger=True` - see code below), but if I run the code via a daemon process, (i.e., `run_from_debugger=False`), `async_function` is never executed.

Is it possible to use `multiprocessing.pool` inside a `daemon` process???
I am using `Python-daemon 1.6` as my daemon package (if it matters).

Code:

```
def loop_callback(params):
    #Spawn the process in the pool
    #  Because loop_callback is called many times, often faster than async_function executes,
    #  adding them to a pool allows for parallel execution.
    pool.apply_async(async_function, params)


def run_service():
    # loop is a method that can/will call loop_callback multiple times, and it will call
    #   loop_callback faster than the code in asyc_function executes
    loop(alignment_watch_folder, sleep_duration)


#Class declaration
app = App()

#Declare a pool of processes
#  processes=1 indicates serial execution
pool = Pool(processes=4)

#Either run from a daemon process or not
run_from_debugger = False

#Run the daemon process
if run_from_debugger:
    run_service()
else:
    daemon_runner = runner.DaemonRunner(app)
    daemon_runner.do_action()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the documentation of [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

> **daemon**
>
> The process’s daemon flag, a Boolean value. This must be set before start() is called.
>
> The initial value is inherited from the creating process.
>
> When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.
>
> Note that **a daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes.** Otherwise a daemonic process would leave its children
>   orphaned if it gets terminated when its parent process exits.
>   Additionally, *these are not Unix daemons or services*, they are normal
>   processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic
>   processes have exited.

Since `multiprocessing.Pool` has to create worker processes, you cannot daemonaize a process using it.

Comment: This documentation looks like it is for the `Process` method, and not the `Pool` method, which my question was about. Does the `daemonic process is not allowed to create child processes` apply to `Pool` as well?

Comment: @Brett A `multiprocessing.Pool` is just an object that handles a fixed number of `multiprocessing.Process`es. In fact with a simple test I get an `AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children`. If you are not getting this error then there's an other issue. Are you sure that `asynch_function` is *not* called? Because the `python-daemon` library detaches the process from its terminal so it's normal to see nothing on screen.